# Converting regular grid indices in geopandas multipolygon to gridcell (X,Y) edges for pcolormesh

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, geopandas

I have a regular grid in a geopandas geodataframe which I read in from a shapefile. I want to create a choropleth plot using matplotlib pyplots pcolormesh, which requires that you define the grid cell edges for X and Y. Is there a simple way to get the grid cell edges from the geopandas multipolygon dataframe?

I have done this by manually extracting the minx, miny from the geodataframe geometry column and then appending the maxx and maxy for the last column and row, respectively. But it is super slow and clunky.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample data and the code that you used now? That will make it easier to see how it could be improved.